# Merging the table from 3 dataset to 1

Tags: asp.net, dataset, asp.net-4.0

I am loading three dataset from the database which has

```
Dataset 1 > Table 1 > 10 rows
Dataset 2 > Table 1 > 3 rows
Dataset 3 > Table 1 > 5 rows
```

(All dataset has same column name, same datatype) actually they contains the data based on different select condition)
now I want to merge all three dataset into one like this

> Dataset 4 > Table 1 > 18 rows

Please help how can I do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [DataSet.Merge Method (DataSet)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4swwh51k.aspx) method.  Something like this (not tested):

C#:

```
dataset1.Merge(dataset2);

DataSet dataset4 = dataset1.Merge(dataset3);
```

VB.NET:

```
dataset1.Merge(dataset2)

Dim dataset4 As New DataSet = dataset1.Merge(dataset3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One (flexible) way is using [Enumerable.Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx).

In VB.NET:

```
Dim tblMerged = tbl1.AsEnumerable _
                    .Union(tbl2.AsEnumerable) _
                    .Union(tbl3.AsEnumerable) _
                    .CopyToDataTable()
```

Tested with:

```
Dim tbl1 As New DataTable
Dim tbl2 As New DataTable
Dim tbl3 As New DataTable
Dim col1_1 As New DataColumn("Col1", GetType(String))
Dim col2_1 As New DataColumn("Col1", GetType(String))
Dim col3_1 As New DataColumn("Col1", GetType(String))

tbl1.Columns.Add(col1_1)
tbl2.Columns.Add(col2_1)
tbl3.Columns.Add(col3_1)
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10
    Dim row = tbl1.NewRow
    row(0) = "Tbl1_Value" & i
    tbl1.Rows.Add(row)
Next
For i As Int32 = 1 To 20
    Dim row = tbl2.NewRow
    row(0) = "Tbl2_Value" & i
    tbl2.Rows.Add(row)
Next
For i As Int32 = 1 To 50
    Dim row = tbl3.NewRow
    row(0) = "Tbl3_Value" & i
    tbl3.Rows.Add(row)
Next

Dim tblMerged = tbl1.AsEnumerable.Union(tbl2.AsEnumerable).Union(tbl3.AsEnumerable).CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: Why would one use this instead of `DataTable.Merge`?

Comment: In my opinion LINQ is more flexible, so if you need to add other conditions `Merge` might not be an option anymore and you have to drop this approach. Both approaches are viable for the OP's requirement.

Comment: Sorry about that. I missed the `Unions` in the bottom line. This is a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tim's suggestion if you're looking to merge the two datasets and all of the containing tables, or you can do something like this for specific tables.

```
DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
DataTable table2 = new DataTable();
DataTable table3 = new DataTable();

table1.Merge(table2);
table1.Merge(table3);
```