# Dataset Tables Merging in single dataset with result set

Tags: asp.net, database, data-binding, dataset

I have three result sets and that will be in the Dataset. So each result set has only one Row. No I want to make it into one Table with three rows.

**Example ::**

```
Result Set :: 

ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["A"], 
ds.Tables[1].Rows[0]["B"],
ds.Tables[2].Rows[0]["C"]
```

**My desired Output ::**

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["A"], 
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["B"], 
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["C"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880546/merging-the-table-from-3-dataset-to-1?rq=1

Comment: if we merge Dataset then the whole Dataset will merge but the Tables will be same with index 0,1,2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you not use the [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) method? Start with a clone of the first table and then merge in the data from the other tables?

The Merge method has an option, [MissingSchemaAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.missingschemaaction.aspx), that lets you specify that new columns should be added to the resulting table so it should do what you are after.